# Como importar uma pagina html em outro html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma página inicial onde existe um menu que abre diálogos. Hoje a está tudo em um *html* só, mas eu gostaria de separar, ou seja, desacoplar e deixar esse *html* do *dialog* separado da página inicial.

Comment: Já pensou em usar iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Se não quiser importar o js da w3schools para usar o atributo "w3-include-html" que a Patrícia mencionou, você pode fazer isso utilizando o `<iframe>` do html mesmo. Ou até utilizar uma linguagem de programação para fazer o "include" de um arquivo separado (php ou .NET por exemplo) o qual eu, particularmente, acho mais recomendável.

Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, é possível fazer isso usando JQuery, através da função load.

**Exemplo:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal').load('modal.html');
});
```

Abraços...

Answer (score -1):

Pode utilizar o attributo w3-include-html. Exemplo retirado do site https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```